# What technology is making this website so fast?

Tags: performance, page-speed

If you look at the console while clicking around [this demo website](https://www.fastestwebsite.co/), you'll se the loading times. It's damn fast (I get about 20ms per page from Europe).

What is it making it so fast? Is it just websocket? The site's author claims it's a proprietary technology, but it sounds a bit like smoke and mirrors...

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: At 20ms, it's cached and not a number fetching directly from the web site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. This type of question is better suited for [chat].

Comment: I'm curious where you get 20ms from? Even with caching enabled I get 2+s in Chrome dev tools (UK).

Comment: @Rob, caching disabled.

Comment: @w3dk, testing from Italy.

Comment: It doesn't look very fast to me: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DKlftKoW0AExtDX.jpg

Answer (score 2):

This is using a CDN where the contents are cached close to you. If you didn't do a complete cache clear in your browser, then it's also coming directly from your computer.

They're using some relatively new pre-loading capabilities, too, meaning they can load as little as possible up front to give you the impression the full page is being loaded when it's really being loaded later. It's not really loading that cleanly for me.

I get 68ms for the initial HTML. Still pretty good but not something anyone else can't achieve. You can go to builtwith.com to get a list of most, if not all, of the tech they use.

Comment: Do you see any break-through technology at work here, like the author claims?

Comment: @chris No, I see nothing different.